# Why Does transmission speed gradually reduce when copying to my external hard drive sometimes?

Tags: hard-drive, nautilus, copy

when I copy Files to my hard drive from nautilus transmission speed start From A high value like 25 mbps and gradually reduce near the end and become very slow. but sometimes it works at normal speed. why is this is there any fix?

Comment: Just a tip - one can achieve better results if the source file(s) is/are compressed into one zip file and then copied or moved.